# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to insert hyperlink to my survey i am getting this error in this line var myspan1 = $(“span[title=’Laptop’]”);

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready( function() {
 var myspan1 = $(“span[title=’Laptop’]”);
 myspan1.append(‘<a target=”_blank” style=”vertical-align:middle;       color:#0072c6″  href=”@http://doc/IT/IT%20Library/SP_UAT%20Server%20and%20Services%20Error.PNG” > <b>[Show]</b></a>’);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single and double quotes properly. Try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var myspan1 = $("span[title='Laptop']");
    myspan1.append("<a target='_blank' style='vertical-align:middle;color:#0072c6'  href='@http://doc/IT/IT%20Library/SP_UAT%20Server%20and%20Services%20Error.PNG'> <b>[Show]</b></a>");
});
```

Comment: Give proper url in href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious problems with your quotes (mixing single and doubles, even unrecognized characters). Take a look to this:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
  var myspan1 = $("span[title=’Laptop’]");
  myspan1.append("<a target='_blank' style='vertical-align:middle; color:#0072c6'  href='@http://doc/IT/IT%20Library/SP_UAT%20Server%20and%20Services%20Error.PNG'> <b>[Show]</b></a>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has problem with quotes
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87zoed6s/)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var myspan1 = $('span[title="Laptop"]');
  myspan1.append("<a target='_blank' style='vertical-align:middle; color:#0072c6'  href='@http://doc/IT/IT%20Library/SP_UAT%20Server%20and%20Services%20Error.PNG'> <b>[Show]</b></a>");
 });
```